# how to understand the definition of \uncover in beamer source code

Tags: beamer, macros, expansion

In beamer, `\uncover` is defined by

```
\newrobustcmd*{\uncover}{\alt{\beamer@fakeinvisible}{\beamer@makecovered}}
```

and `\alt` is defined by

```
\newrobustcmd*\alt{\@ifnextchar<{\beamer@alt}{\beamer@alttwo}}
\long\def\beamer@alttwo#1#2{\beamer@ifnextcharospec{\beamer@altget{#1}{#2}}{#1}}
\long\def\beamer@altget#1#2<#3>{%
  \gdef\beamer@doifnotinframe{#2}\def\beamer@doifinframe{#1}%
  \beamer@masterdecode{#3}\beamer@donow}
\long\def\beamer@alt<#1>#2#3{%
  \gdef\beamer@doifnotinframe{#3}\def\beamer@doifinframe{#2}%
  \beamer@masterdecode{#1}\beamer@donow}
```

So, `\uncover<1>{text}` is expanded to

```
\alt{\beamer@fakeinvisible}{\beamer@makecovered}<1>{text}
```

and then

```
\beamer@alttwo{\beamer@fakeinvisible}{\beamer@makecovered}<1>{text}
```

and then

```
\beamer@ifnextcharospec{\beamer@altget{\beamer@fakeinvisible}{\beamer@makecovered}}{beamer@fakeinvisible}<1>{text}
```

`\beamer@ifnextcharospec` is defined by

```
\long\def\beamer@ifnextcharospec#1#2{%
  \def\reserved@a{#1}%
  \def\reserved@b{#2}%
  \futurelet\@let@token\beamer@ifnch}
\def\beamer@ifnch{%
  \ifx\@let@token<%
    \let\reserved@c\reserved@a%
  \else%
    \let\reserved@c\reserved@b%
  \fi%
  \reserved@c}
```

but I don't understand this piece of code and the effect of `\beamer@ifnextcharospec`.

And then how is the expansion goning on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\beamer@ifnextcharospec` is pretty much `\@ifnextchar<` but spaces aren't ignored. The definition:

```latex
\long\def\beamer@ifnextcharospec#1#2{%
  \def\reserved@a{#1}%
  \def\reserved@b{#2}%
  \futurelet\@let@token\beamer@ifnch}
```

stores the `<true code>` (`#1`) in `\reserved@a` and the `<false code>` in `\reserved@b`, and then does `\futurelet`.  The `\futurelet` call will store the next token in `\@let@token` and then call `\beamer@ifnch`.  `\beamer@ifnch` will compare your token with `<` and assign either `\reserved@a` or `\reserved@b` to `\reserved@c` accordingly, and then execute the latter.

With the call:

```
\beamer@ifnextcharospec % 1
  {\beamer@altget{\beamer@fakeinvisible}{\beamer@makecovered}}% 2
  {beamer@fakeinvisible}% 3
  <1>{text}% 4
```

the next token (the first one is line 4) is indeed a `<`, so `\reserved@a` (line `1`) is executed, so you have:

```
\beamer@altget{\beamer@fakeinvisible}{\beamer@makecovered}
  <1>{text}% 4
```

Finally, you are now sure that what follows is a `<...>`-delimited argument, so `\beamer@altget` will expand correctly:

```
\gdef\beamer@doifnotinframe{\beamer@makecovered}%
\def\beamer@doifinframe{\beamer@fakeinvisible}%
\beamer@masterdecode{1}%
\beamer@donow
  {text}% 4
```

Comment: Clear explanation!